# dism.exe error on driver .cab installation

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, cab, dism

I'm trying to install .cab file on Windows 8.1. The file contains a driver and was downloaded from the Microsoft Update Catalog. File's path is `e:\audio.cab` and I use the following command (in elevated mode):

```
dism /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:E:\audio.cab /NoRestart
```

and I get:

```
An error occured trying to open - audio.cab Error: 0x80070002
Error: 2
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Why is that? The path seems valid.

Comment: what is this audio.cab? Where did you get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Microsoft Update Catalog

Apart from updates, the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/) also provides driver packaged in [cabinet archives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_%28file_format%29). Such drivers are meant to be installed manually after unpacking them, e.g using [7-Zip](http://7zip.org/).

---

## Manually installing a driver

1. Download and extract the driver package.
2. Open the [Device Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/where-is-device-manager).
3. Locate the device you want to update, right-click it, and select **Update Driver Software** from the context menu.
4. Click **Browse my computer for drivers software**.
5. Click the **Browse** button, and select the folder where you extracted the driver. Click **OK** when done.
6. Click **Next**. The driver should start installing.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently you should add an angle bracket (`>`) after the drive letter in the package path:

`dism /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:E:\>audio.cab /NoRestart`

** Please note the comments below about the exact position of the `>` angle bracket.

This worked for me with this problem on Windows 10 21H1.

Credit should go to KazuyaKisho on thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bfab127c-9199-40b2-9b2a-8aa7ee6e351c/quotthe-system-cannot-find-the-file-specifiedquot-error-when-installing-package-using-dism-and?forum=w7itproinstall

Comment: WARNING: The linked TechNet post's instructions are slightly different! The TechNet post indicates placement of the angle bracket as "C:\>" while this post indicates it as "C:>\". I added the angle bracket as indicated by this post, and CMD parsed it as a redirect and overwrote my 2GB CAB with textual console log output saying it couldn't find any packages to process (presumably at "C:")... I'm on a relatively slow connection and have to spend another couple hours downloading the CAB again...

Comment: Just a follow-up on my experience: I tried the angle bracket as the TechNet post indicated, and good news, it didn't wipe the CAB, but bad news, it didn't work at all. Still can't find the file that's definitely there.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the overwrite! I can't honestly remember which way around it worked for me.
I have edited the post above to show `E:\>`.
I have a vague feeling that having tried that, I actually managed to get it to work my original `E:>\ ` way, but I don't have an environment to test again any more.
I recommend everyone firstly take a backup of their CAB file, then try `E:\>audio.cab`, then if that fails try `E:>\audio.cab`.
Please let us know which works!